# Is there any penalty for summoning?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

A few times now, usually during a boss fight, I get the <kbd>L2</kbd> `Summon` prompt. I've always chosen to do it and it ends the fight with a flashy cutscene that leaves the surrounding area incinerated for a bit. Is there any negative outcome for doing this, like getting less EXP or lower grades for the fight? Since this usually happens during unique fights, I can't tell if I'm getting less EXP than normal or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience has indicated that only Noctis gains EXP when summoning. Also, it's unreliable in normal fights (seems to show up once every few hours at best).

Comment: There is a cooldown on each summon, so you generally wouldn't want to use them during normal fights as that risks them being unavailable at the next boss fight.